Quantum collapse: our invention?
I'm wondering if a similar scenario has already been proposed, or if this one is somehow valid. I'm a complete layman so be patient.My reasoning goes like this: is the collapse of the wave function a real event or is it just an artifice to describe how we perceive reality? Let me explain: The collapse of the wave function might not be a real event, but a necessary requirement to understand the reality of our mind. The wave function could remain in a superposition state even after a measurement, and therefore reality could constantly exist in a superposition state. We only "created" the collapse of the wave function to interpret it with our language.

What experiment do you propose to distinguish your two scenarios?

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/749475/is-collapse-of-wavefunction-actually-relative/749500#749500
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149967/wave-function-collapse-versus-decoherence/150029#150029
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/742924/quantum-wave-function-collapse-by-unknown-observer/742930#742930

All of mathematics is a human invention. Abstract mathematical objects only exist in human minds. But they are what we use to model physics. They are not as sharp a tool as we would like, but that's life.
The phenomena of the real world have their own nature: it isn't mathematical. Therefore, when we use mathematics to model nature, there are places where our imaginary objects simply don't map easily to reality.
In nature, past and future are different things, while mathematical objects are conceived as eternal. This clash strains physics. "Wave function collapse" reflects that strain. But rejoice: the concept works! Many experiments verify this. That's why we use it.
